# Unity physics how to get the force vector that is working on an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am moving a vehicle in Unity C# using addForce. the forward motion is created by an engine component and the steering motion is created by a steering component.
The object moves in the proper direction but I am having problems making it face the direction of travel.
Transform.LookAt wants the direcion to look.
Is there any way to retrieve the resulting force vector that the physics engine calculated other than calculating it myself as well?

Comment: `Rigidbody` hasn't any trace of resulting force. You can read `velocity`, but in order to get the resulting force you should add every forces you apply (with `AddForce`) + the gravity.

Comment: The key here is "making it face the direction of travel." It doesn't sound like you need to know what forces are acting on the object. What you need is velocity, like the other users mentioned. The velocity vector will point in the direction of travel.

Comment: Hey LLSv2.0...from looking at your picture...you should definitely shave :-))  Many thx for pointing that out to me ...looks like too common sense for me. solves my issue! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the velocity in a vector or 3 floats. but there isn't a way to directly store the force that was applied unless you have a stored force that you apply.

to store the velocity use this line of code:

```
     float velX = rb.velocity.x;
     float velY = rb.velocity.y;
     float velZ = rb.velocity.z;
     //this will store all velocities at the time of running the code.
```

or store it as a Vector3 like this:

```
     Vector3 velocities = rb.velocity;
```

*Note* the rigidBody should be defined as rb or you need to change the name of your rigidbody in the code to the name you have.

Comment: thanks Jadon... the key is that the velocitiy vector points in the direction of travel... mayn thanks for helping :-))

Comment: hey my pleasure, i am glad i could help.